# Issue with Creating and Loading Projects in Visual Studio 2022 Community Version

Tags: visual-studio

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Version, and I have encountered an issue while attempting to create multiple projects using ASP.NET and C#.NET. The problem I'm facing is that the projects are not being created or loaded correctly. Could you please provide me with guidance on how to resolve this issue? I'm looking for the best possible solution.

Thank you.

I tried to creates new projects but I couldn't be work, But I checked many ways to do that but still got like this below

[image: After creating the project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by doing the same thing as in the link below, apparently the order of the windows environment variables that was preventing the .NET sdk from working correctly, since even by command line it will not be possible to create applications using .NET

**solution:**

So it seems you installed both versions 32-bit and 64-bit, and so the 32-bit was the first one added to the system's path.

Click on the windows key and start typing Edit the system variables and click on that option
[image: System Environment]

Click on the Environment Variables button
[image: Click the Environment Variables]

Under the System variables, select Path and click the Edit button
[image: Click the Edit Button]

Find the entry C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe and using the Move up button, leave that entry before the x86 one. Here's my machine for example:
[image: Move Bottom to Up]

Click the OK button until all the windows are closed. Open a new command prompt and run where dotnet. This should bring the non x86 first and you should be able to use the SDK now. Let me know if this works!